# Close quickinfo Template programatically in synfusion

Tags: reactjs, calendar, popup

I am using https://www.syncfusion.com/ to create popup quick info template in the calendar view.I have referred to this forum https://www.syncfusion.com/forums/157722/close-quickinfo-template-programatically but not suitable for me because I am using React. May I know how to close the quick info template programmatically in react? Below is my existing coding:

```html
 const handleCloseQuickInfoTemplate = e => {
    this.CloseQuickInfoPopup(); // To programmatically close the quick popup
  };
  
  const headerTemplate = props => {
    console.log('headerTemplate', props);
    return (
      <div class="e-popup-header">
        <div class="e-header-icon-wrapper">
          <button
            class="e-edit e-control e-btn e-lib e-flat e-round e-small e-icon-btn"
            title="Edit"
          >
            <span class="e-btn-icon e-icons e-edit-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <button
            class="e-delete e-control e-btn e-lib e-flat e-round e-small e-icon-btn"
            title="Delete"
            onClick={() => setOpenDeletePopup(true)}
          >
            <span class="e-btn-icon e-icons e-delete-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <button
            class="e-close e-control e-btn e-lib e-flat e-round e-small e-icon-btn"
            title="Close"
            onClick={handleCloseQuickInfoTemplate}
          >
            <span class="e-btn-icon e-icons e-close-icon"></span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="e-subject-wrap">
          <div class="e-subject e-text-ellipsis" title={props.Subject}>
            {props.Subject}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  };

  const contentTemplate = props => {
    let startDateConvert = moment(props.StartTime.toString()).format(
      'MMMM DD, YYYY'
    );
    let startTimeConvert = moment(props.StartTime.toString()).format('h:mm A');
    let endTimeConvert = moment(props.EndTime.toString()).format('h:mm A');

    return (
      <div className="template-wrap">
        <div class="e-date-time">
          <div class="e-date-time-icon e-icons"></div>
          <div class="e-date-time-wrapper e-text-ellipsis">
            <div class="e-date-time-details e-text-ellipsis">
              {startDateConvert} ({startTimeConvert}&nbsp;-&nbsp;
              {endTimeConvert})
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="e-location">
          <div class="e-location-icon e-icons"></div>
          <div class="e-location-details e-text-ellipsis">{props.Location}</div>
        </div>
        <div class="e-resource">
          <div class="e-resource-icon e-icons"></div>
          <div class="e-resource-details e-text-ellipsis">
            {props.DoctorList}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="e-location">
          <div class="e-description-icon e-icons"></div>
          <div class="e-location-details e-text-ellipsis">{props.Type}</div>
        </div>
        <div class="e-location">
          <div class="flaticon-file-1 icon-md"></div>
          <div
            class="e-location-details e-text-ellipsis"
            style={{ paddingLeft: '4%' }}
          >
            {props.Status}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  };
  
  <ScheduleComponent
            cssClass="virtual-scrolling schedule-header-bar"
            width="100%"
            height="100%"
            resizeStop={rescheduleDrag.bind()}
            dragStop={rescheduleDrag.bind()}
            locale={checkLocal()}
            currentView={schedularView}
            eventSettings={{
              dataSource: list.concat(organizerList),
              eventTemplate: eventTemplate.bind(),
            }}
            quickInfoTemplates={{
              header: headerTemplate.bind(),
              content: contentTemplate.bind(),
            }}
            renderCell={onCellRender.bind()}
            eventRendered={onEventRendered.bind()}
            ref={schedular_element}
            actionComplete={onActionComplete.bind()}
            headerIndentTemplate={headerIndentTemplate.bind()}
            rowAutoHeight={true}
            timeScale={{
              enable: true,
              interval: 60,
              slotCount: 60 / timeInterval,
              majorSlotTemplate: majorSlotTemplate.bind(),
              minorSlotTemplate: minorSlotTemplate.bind(),
            }}
            popupOpen={popUpHandler.bind()}
            group={{ byDate: true, resources: ['Doctors'] }}
            selectedDate={startDate}
          >
            <ResourcesDirective>
              <ResourceDirective
                field="Doctor"
                name="Doctors"
                dataSource={
                  selectedDoctorList.length > 0
                    ? filteredDoctorListSchedulerOrDefault()
                    : doctorListScheduler
                }
                textField={'resource'}
                idField={'resource'}
                allowMultiple={true}
              ></ResourceDirective>
            </ResourcesDirective>

            <Inject
              services={[
                Day,
                Week,
                WorkWeek,
                Month,
                TimelineMonth,
                Year,
                Resize,
                DragAndDrop,
              ]}
            />
            <ViewsDirective>
              <ViewDirective
                option="Day"
                endHour="24:00"
                startHour="08:00"
                interval={dateInterval}
                eventTemplate={eventTemplate.bind()}
              />
              <ViewDirective option="Week" startHour="08:00" endHour="24:00" />
              <ViewDirective
                option="WorkWeek"
                startHour="08:00"
                endHour="24:00"
              />
              <ViewDirective option="Month" />
              <ViewDirective option="TimelineMonth" />
              <ViewDirective option="Year" />
            </ViewsDirective>
          </ScheduleComponent>
```

Below the picture X button doesn't work:

[image]